# dotnet-coverage fails on Windows Server 2019 with "Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005"

Tags: windows-server-2019, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

We have a self-hosted GitHub runner on Windows Server 2019. One of the steps in the build action is to merge coverage reports using `dotnet-coverage`.

However, the command always fails with "Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005".

Why does this occur and how can we fix it?

Answer (score -1):

To fix this issue these suggestions maybe useful:

1.Be sure installed .NET runtime on your GitHub server is the same with your project version.

2. enable tracing by setting COREHOST_TRACE=1
   env. variable [more info](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-tracing.md)
3. then run the project and see the output result